# Mockito - thenReturn always returns null object

Tags: java, null, mockito

I'm trying to implement Mockito to test a particular method but the .thenReturn(...) seems to always be returning a null object instead of what I intended:

*CUT:*

```
public class TestClassFacade {

  // injected via Spring
  private InterfaceBP bpService;

  public void setBpService(InterfaceBP bpService) {

      this.bpService = bpService;
  }

  public TestVO getTestData(String testString) throws Exception {

    BPRequestVO bpRequestVO = new BPRequestVO();

    bpRequestVO.setGroupNumber(testString) ;
    bpRequestVO.setProductType("ALL") ;           
    bpRequestVO.setProfileType("Required - TEST") ;

    IBPServiceResponse serviceResponse = bpService.getProduct(bpRequestVO);  //PROBLEM

    if (serviceResponse.getMessage().equalsIgnoreCase("BOB")) {

        throw new Exception();

    } else {

        TestVO testVO = new TestVO();
    }

    return testVO;
  }

}
```

*Spring Configuration:*

```
<bean id="testClass" class="com.foo.TestClassFacade">

   <property name="bpService" ref="bpService" />

</bean>

<bean id="bpService" class="class.cloud.BPService" />
```

*Mockito Test Method:*

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class BaseTest {

    @Mock BPService mockBPService;
    @InjectMocks TestClassFacade mockTestClassFacade;

    private String testString = null;
    private BPRequestVO someBPRequestVO = new BPRequestVO();
    private IBPServiceResponse invalidServiceResponse = new BPServiceResponse();

    @Test (expected = Exception.class)
    public void getBPData_bobStatusCode_shouldThrowException() throws Exception {

        invalidServiceResponse.setMessage("BOB");

        someBPRequestVO.setGroupNumber(null);
        someBPRequestVO.setProductType("ALL");
        someBPRequestVO.setProfileType("Required - TEST");

        System.out.println("1: " + someBPRequestVO.getGroupNumber());
        System.out.println("2: " + someBPRequestVO.getProductType());
        System.out.println("3: " + someBPRequestVO.getProfileType());
        System.out.println("4: " + someBPRequestVO.getEffectiveDate());

        when(mockBPService.getProduct(someBPRequestVO)).thenReturn(invalidServiceResponse);

        mockTestClassFacade.getTestData(testString);

        verify(mockBPService).getProduct(someBPRequestVO);
    }
}
```

*System output:*

```
1: null
2: ALL
3: Required - TEST
4: null
```

What's happening here is that when I run the test the serviceResponse object is null on the line in the CUT marked with //PROBLEM above.  My desire is to have that object be populated with my "invalidServiceResponse" object from my test method.  Judging from the output of my System.out.println's it appears that my bpRequestVO matches my someBPRequestVO in content.

Could some one show me what I'm missing here?

Thanks for your time!

Comment: Most likely it fails to match parameters to getProduct that you setup in you when(...) with what is being passed in the actual method. Try using matchers in when(service.getProduct(argThat(...)).thenReturn.

Comment: OP: you shoudl accept @lewthor's answer instead; I was mistaken, overriding `.equals()` is enough, you don't need an argument matcher

Comment: Thanks for the follow-up fge...I had just tested it with the .equals() alone and came back to this page to make sure I didn't misunderstand something.  Sure enough I found your comment!  I have switched the accepted answer.
Thanks for your honesty.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The instance of BPRequestVO that you use with `when()` is different than the one used in `getTestData()`.
Unless you override `equals()`, they will not match.

You should not need to write a custom Matcher if you override equals(). Note the following from the [Mockito documentation](https://mockito.googlecode.com/hg-history/1.7/javadoc/org/mockito/Matchers.html):

> "Custom argument matchers can make the test less readable. Sometimes it's better to implement equals() for arguments that are passed to mocks (Mockito naturally uses equals() for argument matching). This can make the test cleaner."

Comment: Thanks lewthor!  I added the .equals() (and .hashcode) in the BPRequestVO and I am now seeing a populated serviceResponse object in my CUT when I run my test case.

Answer (score 26):

Instead of creating a equals method in your BPRequestVO class you can create a mock argument with "any(YourObject.class)" like this:

```
when(mockBPService.getProduct(any(BPRequestVO.class))).thenReturn(invalidServiceResponse);
```

Comment: any(YourObject.class) is simply the answer. Don't know why the other posts outsmart themselves. Upvote

Answer (score 11):

The problem is in your usage of `when()`.

You submit a reference to a constructed instance; as a result, the mocking will return what you want only if the argument passed to the method is *the same reference*.

What you want is an argument matcher; something like:

```
when(mockBPService.getProduct(argThatMatches(someBPRequestVO))
    .thenReturn(whatYouWant);
```

Of course, it requires that you write the argument matcher!

Note that there is a builtin matcher which can do what you want:

```
when(mockBPService.getProduct(eq(someBPRequestVO))).thenReturn(whatYouWant);
```

This matcher of course requires that your `BPRequestVO` class implements `equals()` (and `hashCode()` too)!

Comment: This saved me. Thanks! Instead of eq() one can use any() as well. Just easier in my opinion.

Answer (score 6):

My problem was that mocked services were defined as final.

Comment: then how did you fix it. As I cant remove final as all services are singelton

Comment: @RishiBansal You should then instantiate the test service and inject mocked services through the contractor.
For example: MyService testableService = new MyService(mockedService1, mockedService2...)

Answer (score 2):

The BPRequestVO Object instance used for mocking is different than Instance used while junit execution.

The best way is to configure any instance of the object while mocking

```
when(mockBPService.getProduct(someBPRequestVO)).thenReturn(invalidServiceResponse);
```

Can be updated with

```
when(mockBPService.getProduct(Mockito.any(BPRequestVO.class))).thenReturn(invalidServiceResponse);
```

Answer (score 0):

My issue was passing null as method arguments doesn't match the when() clause I set up.

e.g.

```
Car car = mock(Car.class)
when(car.start(anyString()).thenReturn("vroom");
assertEquals("vroom", car.start(null));
```

This would fail.

```
assertEquals("vroom", car.start("Now"));
```

This passes.

Answer (score 0):

My issue was with the instance of the service which is autowired/mockbean had different instance at the Test->given() part and whi lein the execution it had different instance.

This was found by running the test in debug mode and checking each value in the mock stub and execution code. If all the parameters and the mocked instance are same then only the thenReturn() will return the expected value.

In myscenario the mocked instance of the class had multiple implementations and by adding @Qualifier("name") the instance became same in the given() and real execution.