# Springboot test issue: Mockito is returning empty object

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, mockito

I am trying to build a prototype that is using gradle as build tool and openjdk-11. This prototype will build a rest-api on springboot framework.

**My module is working fine with rest-api call and returning expected result**. However, as I am now trying to write a test for the rest api, the test is failing as Mockito is returning empty object. Would appreciate any insight on how should I write a test for this rest-api or what to do to fix it.

**My controller:**

```
@RestController
public class GreetingController {

private static final String template = "Hello, %s!";
private final AtomicLong counter = new AtomicLong();

@Autowired
GreetingService service;

@RequestMapping("/greeting")
public Greeting greeting(@RequestParam(value="name", defaultValue="World") String name) {
    return service.getGreetings(0L, String.format(template, name));
}
}
```

**The service:**

```
@Service
public class GreetingService {

public Greeting getGreetings() {
    return new Greeting(1L, "Hello World");
}

public Greeting getGreetings(Long id, String name) {
    return new Greeting(id, name);
}
}
```

**The Model:**

```
@Builder
@Data
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@JsonDeserialize(builder = Greeting.class)
public class Greeting {
    @NonNull
    private Long id;

    @NonNull
    private String content;

}
```

**The main class:**

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

I executed this by :

```
gradle bootrun
```

**And then from browser, tried :**

```
http://localhost:8080/greeting
```

**And that returned:**

```
{"id":0,"content":"Hello, World!"}
```

**Again  tried:**

```
http://localhost:8080/greeting?name=Patty
```

**and that returned:**

```
{"id":0,"content":"Hello, Patty!"}
```

**Now, I was trying to write test to validate api calls similar to the above calls programatically. So I tried:**

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class GreetingControllerTest {

    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Mock
    private GreetingService service;

    @InjectMocks
    private GreetingController controller


    @Test
    public void testGreeting() throws Exception {

        Greeting  greeting  = new Greeting(0L,"Patty!");
        String expectedResponse  = "{\"id\":0,\"content\":\"Hello, Patty!\"}";


        //JacksonTester.initFields(this, new ObjectMapper());
        mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(controller)
                .build();
        Mockito.when(service.getGreetings(0L,"Patty")).thenReturn(greeting);


        MockHttpServletResponse response = mockMvc
                .perform(get("/greeting?name=Patty")
                        .contentType(MediaType.ALL))
                .andReturn()
                .getResponse();


        assertThat(response.getStatus()).isEqualTo(HttpStatus.OK.value());
        assertThat(response.getContentAsString()).isEqualTo(expectedResponse)


    }




}
```

**The error msg is :**

```
org.junit.ComparisonFailure: 
Expected :"{"id":0,"content":"Hello, Patty!"}"
Actual   :""
```

**Failing from this line:**

```
assertThat(response.getContentAsString()).isEqualTo(expectedResponse)
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you aware that your test needs a running server? You can only test against your running application this way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This helped me understanding: [Mockito - thenReturn always returns null object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26680678/mockito-thenreturn-always-returns-null-object)

I changed the Mockito.when part to :

```
Mockito.when(service.getGreetings(Mockito.anyLong(),Mockito.anyString())).thenReturn(greeting);
```

and it worked